# Parsing json using jquery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am new to json/jquery. Please help.

I have a database with list of cities/states. I get it and in the html document and use json_encode to get the json in a javascript object.

```
var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($query); ?>');
```

It looks like:

```
"[
     {"city":"Aaronsburg","state_code":"PA"}, 
     ...
     {"city":"Abbeville","state_code":"AL"}
]"
```

I am trying to use the following to access each city/state:

```
$.each(json_obj, function() {
       $("<div>" + json_obj['state_code']+"/div>").appendTo('#test'); // I also tried json_obj.state_code
});
```

What I get in the output is:

```
undefined
...
undefined
```

What i need to do is actually print the city/state

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curreent value is passed by jQuery as:

```
$.each(json_obj, function(index, value) {
    $("<div>" + value.state_code + "/div>").appendTo('#test');
});
```

Take a look at the [specs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).